# Ribs safety after outside defrosting

Tags: pork

I defrosted a package of unopened sealed ribs outside for an hour and a half because I was short on time. I did not think it would be a problem, but after reading all the different posts, I am a little concerned. The package was sealed, so are they okay to eat? i rinised them and salted them and they are in the oven...

Comment: 'outside' is likely affected by where you are, and when it is.  I've defrosted frozen turkeys outside for Christmas ... but it was fridge-like temperatures at the time, with water (and some ice) for thermal mass.

Comment: You say that you read other posts, but you seem likely to have missed our main post about defrosting outside, which explains the exact time limits of the danger zone.

Answer (score 0):

[From the FDA:](http://www.fsis.usda.gov/shared/PDF/Danger_Zone.pdf) Food temperatures between 40 °F and 140 °F, are ideal for bacteria.This range of temperatures is often called the “Danger Zone.” Never leave food out of refrigeration over 2 hours. If the temperature is above 90°F, food should not be left out more than 1 hour.

That said, if your ribs were frozen to begin with, then it certainly took 'some time' to reach 40°F and was likely not in "the danger zone" for over an hour, and 'should be' safe.